# What is purpose of xsd:union in XML Schema (XSD)?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am parsing XSD for some purpose but facing issues with some XSD nodes. What is the use of the union in XSD  and why it is used.

Is it used to put some sort of restriction on XML?  I am attaching union and simple type node.

Please explain why it is used ?

```
<xsd:simpleType name="PeriodExtendedEnum">
    <xsd:union memberTypes="PeriodEnum">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
                <xsd:enumeration value="T" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:union>
</xsd:simpleType>


<xsd:simpleType name="PeriodEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
        <xsd:enumeration value="D" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="W" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="M" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Y" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 9):

The [**`xsd:union`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#derivation-by-union) element allows derivation of a new type consisting of the *union* in the set theoretical sense of the types of its memberTypes.

In your example, `PeriodExtendedEnum` is the union of `PeriodEnum` {`D`, `W`, `M`, `Y`} and {`T`}:  That is, `PeriodExtendedEnum` would allow all of the values of its two memberTypes: {`D`, `W`, `M`, `Y`, `T`}.